# Replace string in .tex file then compiled by latex

Tags: macros, luatex

The document is created from different file and included using `\input{filename.tex}`. In all these file I want to replace a string by a new string but not losing grammar and pulling checking provide by the editor.

For example replace `latex` or `Latex` by `Custom-\LaTeX{}`.

a preferable solution is not to defined an addition commend in which the text must to be replace. I am looking form similar to C/C++ `#define` directive.

### Update using chickenize

When using

```
\addtosubstitutions{latex}{Latex}
\substitutewords
```

the .bbl could not be generated by biblatex

When using

```
\addtosubstitutions{latex}{Latex\ae}
\substitutewords
```

the error was

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/chickenize/chickenize.tex)) [\directlu
a]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\T'.
\addtosubstitutions ...tosubstitutions("#1","#2")}

l.84 \addtosubstitutions{latex}{Latex\ae}
```

Comment: the entire TeX language is a macro processing language not dissimilar to the C macro pre-processor, so in latex you would normally have input \foo which you can define using `\def` or `\newcommand` similar to `#define`, but you are suggesting input being `latex` rather than a macro. You did not mention luatex in the question but you tagged the question luatex, if that is a possibility you can use the input buffer callback to make arbitrary lua pattern string replacements o the input (see the chikenize package for some good examples)

Comment: you can replace some string with function `replace` in your editor. some editor enable to do this in all open files in editor.

Comment: @ David: both \def and \newcommand require the string to start with '\'. Do you have link to chikenize package I can't find it.

Comment: @ Zarko: the editors replace function will also replace the text that the spelling/grammar checker see.

Comment: while you can use lua here it isn't at all clear why you do not want to use tex macros which are by far the most natural mechanism to use in TeX? What is so bad about starting with `\ ` hard to use tex and avoid `\ `

Comment: Using a macro to \newcommand{\formulae} {formul\ae} I expect that a spell/grammar checker cannot work with \formulae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\addtosubstitutions` macro is not escaping strings correctly.  You could either fix it in the call to `\addtosubstitutions` using

```
\addtosubstitutions{latex}{\luaescapestring{Latex\ae}}
```

or you could override the definition

```
\def\addtosubstitutions#1#2{
  \directlua{addtosubstitutions("\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{#2}")}
}
\addtosubstitutions{latex}{Latex\ae}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chickenize}
\def\addtosubstitutions#1#2{
  \directlua{addtosubstitutions("\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{#2}")}
}
\addtosubstitutions{latex}{Latex\ae}
\substitutewords

\begin{document}

latex

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I filed a [pull request](https://github.com/alt/chickenize/pull/3) against the upstream source to fix this bug, so a new version might not require this workaround.

Comment: The chickenize package did not work for me: Even adding `\usepackage{chickenize}` to my LaTeX file prevented it from compiling.